# Django 1-1 relationship how to

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

```
profile = UserProfile.objects.get(....)
```

what i try to do - is to get profile for the currently logged in user. What should i put in the brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are following the pattern described here:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

You should be able to use the following:

```
def my_view(request):
    user = request.user
    if not isinstance(user, AnonymousUser):
        profile = user.get_profile()
        # do something with the profile here
    else:
        # handle anonymous users
```

Answer (score 2):

Comon guys, no need to be so harsh... Some people actually don't know that the grey outline checkmark is what you're supposed to press.

```
UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

But if it's a `OneToOne` field, you should be able to do `request.user.userprofile`
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#one-to-one-relationships

Comment: Thank you Yuji, it was exactly it. Sorry, im still a very beginner ^^